# ERROR: ld.so: object 'libproxychains.so.3' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored

Tags: ld-preload

When I type the command
`proxychains chromium` on linux terminal

it gives me this error:

`ERROR: ld.so: object 'libproxychains.so.3' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored. Opening in existing browser session.`

what should I do in order to get rid of this error and make sure that proxychains work properly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've faced the same problem, when trying to run something like :

```
proxychains ping -c www.google.com
```

but when trying to run something else like to get my public ip addr :

```
proxychains curl ifconfig.me
```

surprisingly it works flawlessly

What i did to fix it was :

1. First i searched for `libproxychains.so.3` location :

   ```
   whereis libproxychains.so.3
   ```

   Output :

   ```
   libproxychains.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3
   ```
2. Next i took a look at the proxychains script `/usr/bin/proxychains` :

   ```
   sudo cat /usr/bin/proxychains
   ```

   Output :

   ```
    #!/bin/sh
    echo "ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)"
    if [ $# = 0 ] ; then
        echo " usage:"
        echo "     proxychains <prog> [args]"
        exit
    fi
    export LD_PRELOAD=libproxychains.so.3
    exec "$@"
   ```
3. Edited the script `sudo nano /usr/bin/proxychains` and changed the export to include the absolute path to  `libproxychains.so.3`:

   ```
    export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3
   ```

   like this :

   ```
    #!/bin/sh
    echo "ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)"
    if [ $# = 0 ] ; then
        echo " usage:"
        echo "     proxychains <prog> [args]"
        exit
    fi
    export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3
    exec "$@"
   ```

Check again, the Error gone.

You can also install proxychains4 that it is better in my opinion (you can use both if you wanted)

to install proxychains4 : `sudo apt install proxychains4`